# Named Entity Recognition for Python error

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

So Im trying to write a text pre-processor and trying to get nltk.ne_chunk() to work but Im getting a host of errors for the following code

```
z = "Francois Legault of the CAQ will now become the new premier of Quebec. This is possible as his party defeated the Liberals in the Provincial elections held on October 1st 2018."

def preprocess_pipe1(doc1):
sent1 = nltk.sent_tokenize(doc1)
#print(sent1)
print(" ")
print ("SENTENCE SPLITTER")
for x in sent1:
    print(x)

print(" ")

sent1 = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent2) for sent2 in sent1]
#print(sent1)
print(" ")
print ("TOKENIZER")
for x in sent1:
    print(x)

print(" ")

sent1 = [nltk.pos_tag(sent2) for sent2 in sent1]
#print(sent1)
print(" ")
print ("POS TAGGER")
for x in sent1:
    print(x)

return(sent1)


sent2=preprocess_pipe1(z)
sent3=nltk.ne_chunk(sent2)
print(sent3)
```

`
The errors are as follows

SENTENCE SPLITTER
Francois Legault of the CAQ will now become the new premier of Quebec.
This is possible as his party defeated the Liberals in the Provincial elections held on October 1st 2018.

TOKENIZER

```
['Francois', 'Legault', 'of', 'the', 'CAQ', 'will', 'now', 'become', 'the', 'new', 'premier', 'of', 'Quebec', '.']
['This', 'is', 'possible', 'as', 'his', 'party', 'defeated', 'the', 'Liberals', 'in', 'the', 'Provincial', 'elections', 'held', 'on', 'October', '1st', '2018', '.']


POS TAGGER
[('Francois', 'NNP'), ('Legault', 'NNP'), ('of', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('CAQ', 'NNP'), ('will', 'MD'), ('now', 'RB'), ('become', 'VB'), ('the', 'DT'), ('new', 'JJ'), ('premier', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('Quebec', 'NNP'), ('.', '.')]
[('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('possible', 'JJ'), ('as', 'IN'), ('his', 'PRP$'), ('party', 'NN'), ('defeated', 'VBD'), ('the', 'DT'), ('Liberals', 'NNS'), ('in', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('Provincial', 'NNP'), ('elections', 'NNS'), ('held', 'VBD'), ('on', 'IN'), ('October', 'NNP'), ('1st', 'CD'), ('2018', 'CD'), ('.', '.')]
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Robin
>   Karlose/PycharmProjects/NLTK Test 1/Code 5 - NER test.py", line 71, in
>   
>       sent3=nltk.ne_chunk(sent2)   File "C:\Users\Robin Karlose\PycharmProjects\NLTK Test
>   1\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk__init__.py", line 177, in
>   ne_chunk
>       return chunker.parse(tagged_tokens)   File "C:\Users\Robin Karlose\PycharmProjects\NLTK Test
>   1\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\named_entity.py", line 123, in
>   parse
>       tagged = self._tagger.tag(tokens)   File "C:\Users\Robin Karlose\PycharmProjects\NLTK Test
>   1\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 63, in tag
>       tags.append(self.tag_one(tokens, i, tags))   File "C:\Users\Robin Karlose\PycharmProjects\NLTK Test
>   1\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 83, in tag_one
>       tag = tagger.choose_tag(tokens, index, history)   File "C:\Users\Robin Karlose\PycharmProjects\NLTK Test
>   1\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 632, in
>   choose_tag
>       featureset = self.feature_detector(tokens, index, history)   File "C:\Users\Robin Karlose\PycharmProjects\NLTK Test
>   1\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 680, in
>   feature_detector
>       return self._feature_detector(tokens, index, history)   File "C:\Users\Robin Karlose\PycharmProjects\NLTK Test
>   1\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\named_entity.py", line 56, in
>   _feature_detector
>       pos = simplify_pos(tokens[index][1])   File "C:\Users\Robin Karlose\PycharmProjects\NLTK Test
>   1\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\named_entity.py", line 186, in
>   simplify_pos
>       if s.startswith('V'): return "V" AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Funnily enough when Im running this code the NER is working just fine

```
import nltk
import nltk.corpus

sent = nltk.corpus.treebank.tagged_sents()[22]
print(sent)
print(nltk.ne_chunk(sent))
```

As far as I understand it - in both cases Im sending POS tagged text to the NLTK named entity recognition function (i.e. nltk.ne_chunk() ) but for the life of me I cannot understand why there are so many errors in the first case.

I would be grateful if anyone can provide some insight into this matter!

Comment: `sent2` seems like a list of list, whereas `nltk.ne_chunk()` accepts a list

Comment: The `tagged_sents` format is different; printing the sample you process should reveal how exactly.